# Temporary local execution of VM image

Tags: virtual-machine

I work with a number of different specialized and configured OS environments but I generally only use one at a time.  I have a processor-beefy laptop but storage is always an issue.  It would also be good to have a running backup of each environment so I can work from other hardware.

What would be ideal would be if I could run some kind of VM library server that maintained canonical copies of each environment from which I could DL local execution copies to my local machine to work with and then stream changes back to the server image as I did my work.

In my research it seems like a number of the virtual machine providers used to have services like this (Citrix Player, VMWare Mirage) but that they have all been EOLd.

Is there a way to set something like this up today?   I'd love a foss solution based on KVM but id be willing to take a free proprietary solution.

Comment: Do you need the VMs to actually run on your machine? I run the VMs on the server and use whichever remote access tool I need at the moment.

Comment: Yes, thats the goal.  I do a lot of computing in odd places where good networking may not be available.  I also connect to special purpose local peripherals like AR headsets.